# Does gimbal for education exist?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, education, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

I have been looking for a gimbal for a long time. Something similar to what you see in the book.

However, I have had a lot of problem to find something similar. All my search results end to

- %95: Camera stablizer
- %5: Lamp holders with adjustable direction.

Is there any keyword to lead me to an educational gimbal like this?

[image: Gimbal]

Comment: Try googling "gyroscope gimbal". Sadly Edmund Scientific is now only Edmund Optics.